# I am building a lottie component and trying to send the path as a props but it does not work why

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
export default function Lottie({isActive,path}) {
  const {colors}=useTheme()
  const animation = useRef(null)
  const top=new Animated.Value(0)
  const opacity=new Animated.Value(0)

  useEffect(() => {
      if(isActive){
        Animated.timing(top,{toValue:0,duration:0,useNativeDriver:false}).start()
        Animated.timing(opacity,{toValue:1,useNativeDriver:false}).start()
        animation.current.play();
      }
      else{
        Animated.timing(top,{toValue:screenHieght,duration:0,useNativeDriver:false}).start()
        Animated.timing(opacity,{toValue:0,useNativeDriver:false}).start()
        animation.current.loop=false;
      }
  }, [isActive])


return (
    <Animated.View style={[styles.lottie,{backgroundColor:colors.background,opacity:opacity,top:top}]}>
    <LottieView
        autoPlay={false}
        loop
        source={require(path)}
        ref={animation}
      />
    </Animated.View>
  );
}
```

here i am trying to send a path and use it in source={require(path)}
.........................................................................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead try this

```
<Lottie source={require('../path/file.json')} />
```